# Hazelcast on deployed servers throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and locally not

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I wanted to upgrade to Java 11 and tomcat 9 my spring boot application that uses Hazelcast 3.12.9 as cashing mechanism. When I deployed locally everything looks to work fine and the caching successfully works. But when the application runs on the cluster, I receive from all 3 nodes that are available the following error:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.some.service.some.server.domain.ClassA
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:77)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:187)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.toObject(MapProxySupport.java:1237)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:120)
    at com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache.lookup(HazelcastCache.java:162)
    at com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache.get(HazelcastCache.java:67)
    at com.some.service.some.server.domain.ClassACache.get(GlassACache.java:28)
    at com.some.service.some.server.domain.ClassAFacade.getClassA(ClassAFacade.java:203)
    at com.some.service.some.server.domain.ClassAFacade.getGlassA(ClassAFacade.java:185)
    at com.some.service.some.server.domain.ClassALogic.lambda$getClassAInParallel$1(ClassALogic.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:952)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:926)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:327)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.some.service.some.server.domain.ClassA
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:288)
```

Hazelcast customizer :

```
@Configuration
public class ClassAHazelcastConfig {
    private static final MaxSizePolicy HAZELCAST_DEFAULT_MAX_SIZE_POLICY = MaxSizePolicy.PER_NODE;
    private static final EvictionPolicy HAZELCAST_DEFAULT_EVICTION_POLICY = EvictionPolicy.LRU;

    @Bean
    HazelcastConfigurationCustomizer customizer(CachePropertiesHolder cacheProperties) {
        return config -> {
            config.addMapConfig(new MapConfig()
                    .setName(CLASS_A_CACHE)
                    .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(cacheProperties.getMaxsize(), HAZELCAST_DEFAULT_MAX_SIZE_POLICY))
                    .setEvictionPolicy(HAZELCAST_DEFAULT_EVICTION_POLICY)
                    .setTimeToLiveSeconds(cacheProperties.getTtl()));

            config.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(
                    new SerializerConfig()
                            .setImplementation(new OptionalStreamSerializer())
                            .setTypeClass(Optional.class)
            );
        };
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CachePropertiesHolder.class)
public class CacheConfig implements CachingConfigurer, EnvironmentAware, ApplicationContextAware {

    public static final String CLASS_A_CACHE = "CACHE_A";

    private Environment environment;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    @Bean(name="cacheManager")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        boolean cachingEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(environment.getProperty("cache.enabled"));
        if (cachingEnabled) {
            HazelcastInstance instance = (HazelcastInstance) applicationContext.getBean("hazelcastInstance");
            return new HazelcastCacheManager(instance);
        }
        return new NoOpCacheManager();
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return new SimpleCacheResolver(Objects.requireNonNull(cacheManager()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new SimpleCacheErrorHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(@NotNull Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(@NotNull ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Everything works properly fine with Java 8 and tomcat 8.

**Update:**

After some days of investigation, I see that the only place that these exceptions are thrown into a parallel stream that is used.

```
return forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
                    items.parallelStream()
                            .map(item -> {
                                try {
                                    return biFunction.apply(item);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    LOG.error("Error", e);
                                    return Optional.<Item>empty();
                                }
                            })
```

The weird thing is that with Java 8 and tomcat 8 I did not have that issue.

Comment: Please share your code base through github .

Comment: Unfortunately, It is internal code and I cannot do that.

Comment: Search through the whole project for ClassA. If it exists, then you won't get this error.

Comment: It for sure exists and it is part of the basic project.

Comment: You need to upgrade HazelCast as well. Latest version is 4.1.1

Comment: Have you reviewed at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527389/hazelcast-serializable-map-classnotfound-exception @PavlMits

Comment: @AnishB. is there something that has changed in that version relevant to this or just upgrade to check?

Comment: You need to check on that.

Comment: @iswailyildiz I just checked it but apparently, in my case, I do not explicitly define any format or similar things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, it is completely unrelated to Hazelcast. Mostly it is Java 11 difference from Java 8.

In the part that the exception was thrown a ForkJoinPool was used which from Java 11, it is not guaranteed when exactly will be created and it seems to not have the same classloader as the spring application. ([Classes with default access result in NoClassDefFound error at runtime in spring boot project for java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967408/classes-with-default-access-result-in-noclassdeffound-error-at-runtime-in-spring))

I made a wrong assumption because the exception was coming from Hazelcast and I also saw that there were other issues related.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast offers two deployment models: embedded mode and client-server mode. Please check the [relevant documentation section](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.9/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-topology) for more information.

In the former case, you have a **single** JVM and all of your classes are on your *classpath*.

In the latter case, you have at least 2 JVMs, **one for each client** and **one for the member**. It seems you forgot to set up the classpath of the member to reference `ClassA`.

How to set the *classpath* depends on how you launch your Hazelcast members. The method that works in most cases is to use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you very much Nicolas for your answer. I use the embedded deployment model but I am curious why the behavior of the application is different with the upgrade of java from 8 to 11 and tomcat from 8 to 9.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the behavior is not different. Perhaps you had user-code deployment in the past? Impossible to know for sure.

Comment: @PavlMits, please how can I reach you as I am having this same problem but am not using spring boot but traditional spring.